# Can't Select Ubuntu 18.04 Installation Type

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

When I try to run the Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS installer on my Lenovo Yoga 910 I'm stuck here. I want to erase my Windows 10 and just have Ubuntu but it seems as though the installer thinks I want to dual boot. Any suggestions on how to fix this? I would prefer not to  have to make a dual boot.

[image: Select Device for Installation]

Answer (score 0):

On some previous step of Ubuntu installer ask installation type where you can select erase All and install Ubuntu:
[image]

**Is always better if you start installation with Ubuntu Live USB.**

Comment: That screen never appears for me